TizenBrew error, instalatin falied Check certificate error : :Invalid certificate chain with certificate in signature.:<-3>
I can't install TizenBrew on my Samsung QN85D. I have tizenOS 8.0.
I used this instruction:
https://github.com/reisxd/TizenBrew/blob/main/docs/README.md
and this to create certificate profile
https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/get-started/certificates/creating-certificates/
I'm connected with my tv on Device Manager.
I'm getting this error:
`install failed[118, -12], reason: Check certificate error : :Invalid certificate chain with certificate in signature.:<-3>`

I know that certificate is valid. I tried to reinstall tizen studio along with certificates on my PC but nothing is working.
Full log:
C:\tizen-studio\tools\ide\bin>tizen install -n TizenBrewStandalone-New.wgt
Transferring the package...
Transferred the package: C:\tizen-studio\tools\ide\bin\TizenBrewStandalone-New.wgt -> /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/tmp
Installing the package...
--------------------
Platform log view
--------------------
install xvvl3S1bvH.TizenBrewStandalone
package_path /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/tmp/TizenBrewStandalone-New.wgt
app_id[xvvl3S1bvH.TizenBrewStandalone] install start
app_id[xvvl3S1bvH.TizenBrewStandalone] installing[9]
app_id[xvvl3S1bvH.TizenBrewStandalone] installing[19]
app_id[xvvl3S1bvH.TizenBrewStandalone] install failed[118, -12], reason: Check certificate error : :Invalid certificate chain with certificate in signature.:<-3>
spend time for wascmd is [659]ms
Failed to install Tizen application.
Total time: 00:00:02.587

Thanks in advance for any help.
I want to sucesfully install TizenBrew, i tried to reinstall Tizen Studio and certificates, i used instructions on gihub and samsung developer page.

You need to install the Samsung Certificate Extension from the package manager and create a Samsung certification. Then rebuild tizenbrew with the new certificate.
